# Call RecyclerView Item Click Programmatically when Item is not Visible on screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview (RvData) which is having 20 items. 12 items are visible at one time on screen so RvData.childCount returns 12.
I need to click (Programmatically) item number 17 (Index) which is not visible on screen.
When I use
RvData.getChildAt(17).callOnClick()
then it doesn't work as there is no child at Index 17 because there are only 12.

RecyclerView item click is done using onBindViewHolder (Code below)

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.GvItem.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener 
        (AC as ActivityClass).CallActivityFunction(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}
```

How can I achieve my purpose?

Comment: Can you make sure that the items are present of your UI, all of them, while the items you do not want to display at that point are invisible?

Comment: @LajosArpad
All (20) of the items are there but 12 are loaded according to the size of screen. RecyclerView loads only that much items which can be visible on screen. Rest of the items are shown/loaded on scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis of the problem you are having looks correct - item number 17 is not represented in the items that are displayed when you need to do the "click".

Consider decoupling the "click" action from the click listener. You can separate out the code that is executed in the click listener into a separate function and call that function from the click listener and wherever else you need to call it.

```
fun myClickAction() {
        (AC as ActivityClass).CallActivityFunction(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
}

...
// other code that detects when the click action is needed
myClickAction()
...

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.GvItem.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener 
        myClickAction()
    })
}
```

If the click action does something with the view holder, you would have to keep that in the click listener and refactor the non-viewholder code out.